# How to rebuild android test project when only having APK of the application to test (no source code)

Tags: android, apk, test-project

**What I want to do**:
Update an android test-project

**What I have**:
1. The APK of the application under test (aut) - no source code
2. The source code of test-project

**What I did**:
Modified (with a 3rd party app) the source code of the test-project (including the Manifest)

**What I tried**:

```
android update test-project -p <path_to_test_project> --main <path_to_aut>
```

**Problem**: It requires access to the aut source code (I tried running it with the path to the apk, no luck).

Is there any way of doing such?

Btw, in case it matters, my test is an extension of  ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and I'm using Robotium.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out the solution.

I shouldn't use *android update* but simply use *ant*.

So this did the trick

```
ant debug install
```